# Single line file angular.module compiled with coffescript missing semicolon?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

```js
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.12.3
(function() {
  angular.module('mymodule', []);

}).call(this);
```

```html
<html ng-app="mymodule">
      <head>

      </head>

      <body>
        ...Testing...
      </body>
      <script src="app/app.js"></script>
</html>
```

Following coffescript snippet compiles to javascript and gives me browser console error:

```
angular.module 'mymodule', []
```

> SyntaxError: missing ; before statement[Learn More]  app.js:1:5

Comment: The error implies that there is an error somewhere before line 1, column 5. The generated JS looks fine, are you certain this is the `app.js` file where the error is?

Comment: Here is a screenshoot cointaining folder structure and files:https://s30.postimg.org/dt7tclas1/Screenshot_from_2017_02_10_19_34_42.png